# How to make vantajs wave work with react app

Tags: html, reactjs, three.js

I am using vantajs wave library and my issue is how do i get the waves to continue to render on a CSS selector after I click through the tablinks of my react app?
The first error I get is on Brave browser when it says:
"three.r92.min.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'precision' of null"
and doesn't render the wave at all initially.

However, if i go to Google Chrome and look at the background of my selected element there is the wave effect that I implemented provided by https://www.vantajs.com/?effect=waves#(backgroundAlpha:1,color:2105474,shininess:30,waveHeight:15,waveSpeed:1,zoom:1)

But then, after I switch from the home tab to another tab, then come back to home (where my selected element is), the wave effect is no longer behind the selected element as it says:

"vanta.waves.min.js:161 [VANTA] Cannot find element .showcase__container

Here is my HTML:

```
    <meta charset='utf-8' lang="EN-US">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="./src/three.r92.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.vantajs.com/dist/vanta.waves.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>DigitalWebFlex</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/dist/bundle.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
        <script>
            VANTA.WAVES('#showcase__container');
        </script>
</body>
```

And my React:

```
            <div className="showcase__container" id="showcase__container">

                <button className="button button--animated button--white" onClick={this.setPagePortfolio}>Portfolio</button>

            </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

hey you can install vanta using `npm i vanta`

and include three.js in the head

and then

```js
import React from 'react'
import WAVES from 'vanta/dist/vanta.waves.min'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.vantaRef = React.createRef()
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.vantaEffect = WAVES({
      el: this.vantaRef.current
    })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.vantaEffect) this.vantaEffect.destroy()
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div ref={this.vantaRef}>
      /* Foreground content goes here */
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This should help, You can refer to [this page](http://www.lib4dev.in/info/tengbao/vanta/97560949) and [Vanta.js README](https://github.com/tengbao/vanta) for a better understanding

Comment: Link to page you provided does not work, neither does your code.